# Given a function defined in an R env, obtain function parameters

Tags: r, reflection

What I'm trying to do is trivial but I've not found a clear solution to it:

For instance, I have the following function:

```
sample.function <- function(a, b, named="test") {
...
}
```

I wish I could inspect the function and obtain the arguments (maybe as an R list), given `ret` is the returned value of the desired function, fhe following assertions should be all `True`

```
ret <- magicfunction(sample.function)
ret[[1]] == "a"
ret[[2]] == "b"
ret$named == "test"
```

can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work if the function encloses its body with brace brackets (which nearly all functions do). It gives a list whose names are the argument names and whose values are the defaults:

```
sample.function <- function(a, b, named="test") {} # test function

L <- as.list(formals(sample.function))); L
## $a
## 
## $b
## 
## $named
## [1] "test"
```

This is slightly longer but works even for functions whose bodies are not surrounded by brace brackets:

```
head(as.list(args(sample.function)), -1)
# same output

head(as.list(args(sin)), -1) # sin has no {}
## $x
```

Returning to the first example, to examine the default values for missing:

```
sapply(L, identical, formals(function(x) {})$x)
##    a     b named 
## TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Revised**

Comment: I think it's clear I'm a total newbie in R, THANK YOU!

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things you can look at, inside or outside of the function.

```
> f <- function(FUN = sum, na.rm = FALSE) { 
      c(formals(f), args(f), match.fun(FUN))
  }
> f()
$FUN
sum

$na.rm
[1] FALSE

[[3]]
function (FUN = sum, na.rm = FALSE) 
NULL

[[4]]
function (..., na.rm = FALSE)  .Primitive("sum")
```

Comment: `formals(sample.function)` and `names(formals(sample.function))` should be all which is relevant for the problem of Giupo.